# UnboundLocalError: Why this code is giving unboundeLocalError?

Tags: python, pandas, data-wrangling

Why this code is giving error - `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'tab' referenced before assignment`

Here is my code -

```
def univar_tables(col_name):
    if col_name in cat_cols:
        tab = pd.DataFrame(pd.crosstab(df[col_name], columns = "count"))
        tab["Row %"] = tab["count"]/len(df)
    elif col_name in num_cols:
        df["binned"] = pd.qcut(df[col_name], q=10, duplicates ='drop', precision = 2)
        tab = pd.DataFrame(pd.crosstab(df["binned"], columns = "count"))
        tab["Row %"] = tab["count"]/len(df)
    return tab
```

Comment: Borh `if` statement conditions are failing so `tab` is not initialised before the `return` at the end of the function. If there is a default value that makes sense for the function you could initialise `tab` at the start of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error since the `tab` object is created conditionally and it might be possible that both the conditions might fail to satisfy for some input date. You can avoid the error by creating the `tab` object with some defaults `None`.

```
def univar_tables(col_name):
    tab = None
    if col_name in cat_cols:
        tab = pd.DataFrame(pd.crosstab(df[col_name], columns = "count"))
        tab["Row %"] = tab["count"]/len(df)
    elif col_name in num_cols:
        df["binned"] = pd.qcut(df[col_name], q=10, duplicates ='drop', precision = 2)
        tab = pd.DataFrame(pd.crosstab(df["binned"], columns = "count"))
        tab["Row %"] = tab["count"]/len(df)
    return tab
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function (*univar_tables*) has actually 3 paths of execution:

- `col_name in cat_cols`,
- `col_name in num_cols`,
- otherwise (neither the first nor the second condition met).

In first 2 cases *tab* variable is **first** set and **then** referenced.

But in the third case *tab* has not been set and it is only referenced in *return* instruction.

This is probably the actual cause of your error.
Maybe in this (third) case you should set *tab* to some value.